# Sync Telegram Contact with Phone Contact

Tags: contacts, sync, telegram

I have Nexus 5x with android 7 and recently my telegram contacts are not sync with my phone contacts, and my sync option for telegram is on. what should I do to aync my telegram contacts with my phone contacts

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on my Nexus 6P with Android 7.1, while it worked perfectly fine on another Nexus 6 with Android 7.0. Here's what helped:

- reinstall the app (do not open yet)
- go into Android Settings > Accounts > Telegram and enabled Contact sync
- open the app and check Contacts

After this my contacts were synced as expected. No sure why the sync was off for me by default.